# How can I convert a hex Color value to its human-readable string representation?

Tags: c#, colors, windows-store-apps, hex, solidcolorbrush

I want to store a color hex value (such as "#FFFF1493") as its "human-friendly" name (such as "DeepPink").

With help from SLaks and nvoigt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215615/why-is-the-canvas-background-property-a-generic-solidcolorbrush-instead-of-an), I've now got this code:

```
if (sender is Canvas)
{
    var canvas = sender as Canvas;
    var brush = canvas.Background as SolidColorBrush;
    var color = brush.Color;
    String brushColorAsStr = color.ToString();

    IAppSettings appSettings;
    if (App.SaveSettingsLocally)
    {
        appSettings = new AppSettingLocal();
    }
    else
    {
        appSettings = new AppSettingsRemote();
    }
    appSettings.SaveSetting(VisitsConsts.APP_BAR_COLOR_SETTING, brushColorAsStr);
}
```

...but the value in brushColorAsStr is "*#FFFF1493*" (when I click the DeepPink canvas control), and that doesn't work with my code to change the app bar color based on the color selected:

```
String brushColor = appSettings.GetSetting(VisitsConsts.APP_BAR_COLOR_SETTING);
if (null == brushColor) return;

if (brushColor.Equals("Blue"))
{
    CmdBar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
else if (brushColor.Equals("Aqua"))
. . .
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net) I got these suggestions:

```
Color colour = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(brushColorAsStr);
System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(brushColorAsStr);
```

...but "*ColorConverter*" and "*Drawing*" are unresolvable in my app. How can I get a human-readable name from a hex color val?

Comment: The first thing you probably should do is strip out the alpha channel, ie the first two hex digits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a mapping from numbers to names, but the Colors class maps from names to numbers. You can use reflection to build the reverse mapping.

See this previous answer for sample code:
[How to convert a Windows.UI.Color into a string color name in a Windows Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188529/how-to-convert-a-windows-ui-color-into-a-string-color-name-in-a-windows-universa/26198372#26198372)

Answer (score 1):

These links might be helpful for you:

[convert hex code to color name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name)

http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-c-convert-drawing_color-to-html-hex-color-value-and-back-cc8mp.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f92a8d0a-8116-4fa6-8072-0b0f09536847/how-to-convert-the-hex-value-into-its-equivalent-color-name?forum=wpf

Comment: Nope; those, too, use classes that are not available to me / resolvable by me. Don't tell me I will have to end up doing "if color == "gobbledygookHexJunq"..."